# How to plot times on the x-axis with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following the example given [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-show-date-and-time-on-the-x-axis-in-matplotlib) I want to create a plot that shows just the time on the x-axis, not the date. So I modified the example code to the following:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, dates as mdates

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

dates = ["01/02/2020 10:00", "01/02/2020 10:05", "01/02/2020 10:10"]
x_values = [dt.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").date() for d in dates]
y_values = [1, 2, 3]
ax = plt.gca()

formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
locator = mdates.HourLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
plt.plot(x_values, y_values)

plt.show()
```

but instead of showing a range in time from 10:00 to 10:10 I get the following:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two issues were that the time information was being discarded when you had `.date()` chained to `.strptime(...)`, and secondly `HourLocator` was being used instead of `MinuteLocator`.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, dates as mdates

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

dates = ["01/02/2020 10:00", "01/02/2020 10:05", "01/02/2020 10:10"]
x_values = [dt.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") for d in dates]
y_values = [1, 2, 3]
ax = plt.gca()

formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

#Comment out to show fewer minute ticks
locator = mdates.MinuteLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'o-');
```

[image]